# How can i remove/filter out lists count 1 from the main list?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
var groupedCustomerList = pairList
    .GroupBy(u => u.Distance)
    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
    .ToList();

        foreach(List<PosDisPair> list in groupedCustomerList)
        {
          if (list.Count() == 1)
            {
                groupedCustomerList.Remove(list);
            }
        }
```

I'm getting exception on the line:

```
foreach(List<PosDisPair> list in groupedCustomerList)
```

groupedCustomerList is list with many lists inside and i want to remove all the lists that are count 1.

InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: What error do you get? You need to give us more information.

Comment: @DavidG InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: I managed to solve it i needed to add ToList() in the foreach foreach(List<PosDisPair> list in groupedCustomerList.ToList()) now it's working.

Comment: Doing that is forcing you to create more objects that you need. My answer is the easiest option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove items in a collection you are trying to enumerate. The easiest way to filter your list is to use Linq:

```
groupedCustomerList = groupedCustomerList
    .Where(l => l.Count() != 1)
    .ToList();
```